# Sum of three perfect cubes is equal to a perfect fourth

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

How many answers does the following equation have?
$a^3+b^3+c^3=d^4$ where $a, b, c, d\in \mathbb{Z}^+$.

This was asked in a test for gifted math students in 7th grade in Finland. I have been thinking about this and couldn't solve this for my number theory isn't that good.

Could someone help me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you are quoting the problem correctly? There will surely be infinitely many examples.  $a=b=c=3^{4k+1}$ for any $k$, for instance.

Comment: @lulu On the other hand if this is for 7th graders (even gifted ones), a question with a non-trivial number of solutions might be way too difficult.

Comment: @CaptainLama  Sure, but the phrasing seems off.  Granted it may be a translation.  I think it would be fine to ask the kids to produce an infinite family of solutions (not difficult), but the phrasing certainly appears to suggest a finite (or $0$) answer.

Comment: @lulu I worded this poorly. If I remember correctly, it was multiple choice.

Comment: @ENTL  No worries!  But, yes.  That makes sense.  So long as it was clear that "infinitely many solutions" was a possible response.  As a side note, you might be interested to know that, if you drop the condition that $a,b,c>0$ the problem becomes $\textit {extremely}$ difficult.  It is widely believed that every number $n$ that is not of the form $ 9n+4$ or $9n+5$ can be written as the sum of three integer cubes, but nobody knows if this is true or not.

Comment: @lulu : or, to be more specific - becomes "unsolved open research-grade Ph.D. level problem". :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It has an infinite number of solutions. For instance, for any $k\in \mathbb{N}$, take $d=3k^3$, and $a=b=c=3k^4$.

Then
$$ a^3+b^3+c^3=3\cdot 3^3k^{12} = 3^4k^{12}=d^4.$$

Comment: easy and nice (+1)

Answer (score 11):

Note that if $a^3 + b^3 + c^3 = n$, then $(na)^3 + (nb)^3 + (nc)^3 = n^4$.
So you have infinitely many solutions even if you require $a,b,c$ to be distinct.

There are also solutions where $a,b,c$ are pairwise coprime, e.g.

$$ \eqalign{19^3 + 89^3 + 117^3 &= 39^4\cr
            107^3 + 163^3 + 171^3 &= 57^4\cr
            81^3 + 167^3 + 266^3 &= 70^4\cr
            75^3 + 164^3 + 293^3 &= 74^4} $$

Are there infinitely many of those?

[EDIT] See [OEIS sequence A327586](https://oeis.org/A327586)

Comment: E. Grigorief noted that $11^4=12^3+17^3+20^3$.(It's a non-trivial solution, but $a,b,c$ are not pairwise coprime) Décomposition d'un bicarré en une somme de trois cubes. L'Intermédiaire des mathematiciens.,vol.9,1902,319 https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=mdp.39015068170839&view=1up&seq=339   https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=mdp.39015068170839&view=1up&seq=550